# How can I copy an entire row to a different sheet if that row contains today's date?

Tags: excel, filter

I am setting up some payment plans. A row will usually contain 2 to 4 different dates along with customer information. I would like to copy any row containing today's date from Sheet1 to Sheet2.

Thanks for any help and let me know if you  need additional info.

edit: Here is some stuff that is not working:

using advanced filter from Sheet2

```
List Range: Sheet1!$1:$1048576
Criteria Range: =today()
Copy To: $a$1
```

also

```
List Range: Sheet1!$1:$1048576
Criteria Range: =a1   //with a1 containing the formula =today()
Copy To: $b$1
```

Comment: You've been here long enough to know you have to show effort.

Comment: I am really trying man. I just spent 30 mins googling stuff and trying it, but nothing I am trying seems to be working.

Comment: So show what you tried.

Comment: ok, i have edited my post

Comment: PS: Learn to accept correct answers (old & new) by ticking them... Soon you will find no one bothers using their time to help you if you appear ungrateful.

Comment: Good to know, thanks. I haven't been doing so well on stack overflow so far, but I will get the hang of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work.

```
Sub copyIfTodaysDate()

    Dim todaysDate As Date
    Dim rngData As Range
    Dim rngRow As Range
    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim counter As Integer

    todaysDate = Date
    counter = 1

    Set rngData = Worksheets("Table1").UsedRange

    For Each rngRow In rngData.Rows
        For Each rngCell In rngRow.Cells
            If rngCell.Value = todaysDate Then
                rngRow.Copy Worksheets("Table2").Rows(counter).Columns(1)
                counter = counter + 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. This works, but I have to run it each time I want to see what is on today's date. Is there another way which I do not have to run each time? I was under the impression that I could do this with Advanced Filter.

Comment: Yes, you can put the above code in a Workbook_Open event. That way Table2 is automatically filled every time the workbook is opened. However, if your data set is very large this may cost you a lot of time since the code is always executed when you open the workbook.

Comment: Awesome. My data set is relatively small - only about 100 lines. This will work great.

Comment: Glad I was of help. It would be great if you could mark the answer as accepetd. Thank you :)